# Re-enable disabled bootstrap tooltip don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I made input with tooltip which should show on load and disappear on button click wherever user clicks:

```
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip().tooltip('show');
    $('html').click(function () {
      $('#inputID').tooltip('disable').tooltip('hide'); });
```

This works fine.

Now I need to check condition if input is empty, tooltip should re-appear (enable/show) again with different text. Event for text changing is handled like this:

```
$('#inputID').attr('data-original-title', "Changed text").tooltip('enable').tooltip('show');
```

The problem is that whatever I write here or before, like (.tooltip() or .tooltip('enable') ..) it does not re-enable my tooltip because it's not displayed again.
When I comment out first block of code, the text is efficiently changed and tooltip with "Changed text" is displayed.

Why disable/enable don't work and what is the solution?
I am using bootstrap 4.0 and jquery 1.12.4.

Comment: why are you `disabling` it??

Comment: how can i make it disappear in other way os it's only showed once, on page load?